# I am having Issues with JOptionPane and if/else statements

Tags: java, if-statement, joptionpane

I am having trouble with JOptionPane. My program is supposed to ask the user a question, if they answer Y is moves on to the next question. But if they answer N it asks another question. My problem is when the user answers with N it just moves on to the Y question. It is basically moving in the order the questions are asked and not following the parameters of the if-else statement.
Here is my code:

```
   import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    
    public class Helper2 {
    
        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            helpMe(); 
        }
        
        public static void helpMe(){
            String ans = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Does you car turn over? (Y/N)"); 
            if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")){
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Does it run rough? (Y/N)"); 
                if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")){
                    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Did you buy cheap gas (Y/N)");
                } else if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase("N")){
                    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Does it stop poorly? (Y/N)");
                }
    
                
            }else if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your battery is dead");
                
            }else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR"); 
            }
            
            
        }
        }
```

Comment: JOptionPane will return interger value so, you have to code like: String ans = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Does you car turn over? (Y/N)");
int xCorFromUser = Integer.parseInt(x);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't changing the value of `ans` in every question. Try something like this:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Helper2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        helpMe();
    }

    public static void helpMe() {
        String ans = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Does you car turn over? (Y/N)");
        if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
            ans = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Does it run rough? (Y/N)");
            if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                ans = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Did you buy cheap gas (Y/N)");
            } else if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
                ans = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Does it stop poorly? (Y/N)");
            }


        } else if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your battery is dead");

        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I managed to fix it, thank you for your response anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I never redefined `ans`. So I had to put `ans =` before all `JOptionPane` statements except for the last two.